# Ubuntu 14 will not install on netbook

Tags: usb-installation

I have downloaded 14 LTS and used PenDrive to install on a 2GB usb stick. I tested it by "running without installing" on my Acer Aspire One and the first time I ran it there were no problems other than it took sometime to load (as expected). Re-booting I chose the second menu item to install on to hard drive. The screen went blank, the USB drive led flashed and I waited, and waited. The only activity was occasional blinking of the USB LED interspersed with the Wireless connection LED and/or the network connection LED. The Wireless and Network LED's flashed on my router but the Internet LED remained steady. After 20 minutes I got bored, switched off the Netbook and tried again. Same result. I tried running without installing again but now this doesn't work either
Any ideas anyone, please?

Comment: Have you already tried to boot Ubuntu with option `running without installing` and then, after Ubuntu is started, try to install it?